# How to get iframe contents(html) with jQuery and save as a variable?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Problem : a twitter widget on a Wordpress website disappears whenever I resize the window. I think it is caused by some scripts that comes with a theme.
(after the widget disappearing, If I see the source, I still have `<iframe><head></head><body></body></iframe>` tags stays there but the contents inside `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` is gone)

So I am trying to solve this problem by saving the html contents of the `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` of the iframe and automatically append them in the corresponding tags whenever the window resize event detected.

```
var head = jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('head').contents();
var body = jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('body').contents();


jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
    jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('head').append(head);
    jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('body').append(body);
});
```

above is the code I am testing with,

If I type `jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('body').contents();` part inside the Chrome's console, I can get the contents and have no problem saving it in a variable and implement whole functionality exactly the way I want.

However, if I save the above scripts in a footer.php file and implement, then it does not work at all. Moreover, the Chrome console returns nothing (empty variable) when I try check what's in the variables, head and body.

Could anyone please tell me,
If I am going in right direction? or there is a better (safer / more proper) way to solve this kind of problem? 
How I can save the contents(html) of the iframe?

========= **update** // it's solved =============

I solved out this problem by changing the code

```
window.onload = function () {
    var head = jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('head');
    var body = jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('body');

    jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
        jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('head').append(head);
        jQuery('iframe.twitter-timeline').contents().find('body').append(body);
    }); 
};
```

I was quite sure it would work somehow because it worked in chrome's console but just couldn't make it working in a php file as mentioned initially.
Anyway, `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // bla, bla, bla });` didn't work for me but somehow `window.onload = function(){}` worked exactly the way I wanted.
So the problem has been solved.

But Thanks for replies guys.

Comment: How I can save the contents(html) of the iframe? Unfortunately you can not in a manner that is worth the effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: @Matt: I already read the article and replies but wasn't successful for me. I think it's me who don't know how to change my code properly though. The site is working now anyway and I appreciate for you reply. Thanks very much.

Comment: @JimKim: Please add your solution as an answer instead of putting it on the question, so people can see that there is a solution.